# Displaying image from file on public Community Page with Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, customer-community

I am trying to display a list of records on a public Community page using a Lightning Web Component (to sign up to a programme). I can get a list of records and display an image from a static resource for each one. I would like to attach an image file to each tile to differentiate. I can get either the ContentDocument Id and/or the Version Id, but cannot get either to render the image incorrectly. I am using `<img src={fileurl} />` where I am building fileurl in my javascript controller, but nothing I try works. I have tried each of the below with both the Salesforce and Community prefix and the File Id and the Version Id. I am wondering whether I need to build public link for each file or need a Static Resource for each record and link the record to the Static Resource?

- /sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/
- /servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=
- /sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `DistributionPublicUrl` in the [`ContentDistribution`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm) record that corresponds to the file's `ContentVersion` record.

`ContentDistribution` is created when you create a Public Link from the file's action menu in the UI.  You can also create them in Apex.

**UPDATE**: While the `DistributionPublicUrl` can't be used directly in an HTML `img` tag, you can construct a valid img URL using parts of it.  See this code:

```
public static String buildPublicUrl(ContentVersion cVersion, ContentDistribution cDist) {
    String fileType = cVersion.FileType.toLowerCase().capitalize();
    String cVersionId = cVersion.Id;
    String cBodyId = cVersion.ContentBodyId;
    String originalUrl = String.valueOf(cDist.DistributionPublicUrl);
    String cDistParam = originalUrl.substring(originalUrl.indexOf('/a/'));
    String orgId = ConnectApi.Organization.getSettings().orgId;
    String baseDomain = Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm();
    baseDomain = baseDomain.substringBefore('.') + '--c.documentforce.com';
    String theUrl = baseDomain + '/sfc/dist/version/renditionDownload?rendition=ORIGINAL_' +
            fileType + '&versionId=' + cVersionId + '&operationContext=DELIVERY&contentId=' + cBodyId +
            '&page=0&d=' + cDistParam + '&oid=' + orgId + '&dpt=null&viewId=';
    return theUrl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @david! This has been really useful. I actually couldn't get DistributionPublicUrl to work with `img`, but I tried with `ContentDonwloadUrl` on ContentDistribution and that worked nicely!

Comment: @AnthonyMealand sorry, I updated my answer to clarify the use of DistributionPublicUrl.

Comment: Perfect - thanks @david!